# Java Chain Coding

Tags: java, arrays

I am to use freeman chain coding to **traverse** an `image(array)` given below:

```
01000000 01000100 01110010 00011001 00001001 00000100 00000010
```

And with the freeman chain coding i am to have the following output:

```
6, 6, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 7, 7,7, 7, 6
```

However, with the code given below my outputs are not matching what I am to have, any ideas as to why this is happening?

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chain {
 int str,stc,p = 0;
 public static void main (String[] args) {
  Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter the number of Rows: ");
  int r = t.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter the number of Columns: ");
  int c = t.nextInt();
  
  int[][] array = new int[r][c];
  System.out.println("Enter values: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < r ; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
    int h = t.nextInt();
    array[i][j] = h;
    
   }
   
  }
  int str = 0,stc = 0,p = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
   for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    if(array[i][j]==1 && p==0) {
     str = i;
     stc=j;
     p++;
    }
    else if(array[i][j]==1) {
     if(i==str && j > stc)
      System.out.print("0, ");
     else if(i==str && i < stc)
      System.out.print("4, ");
     else if(j==stc && i >str)
      System.out.print("6, ");
     else if(j==stc && i<str)
      System.out.print("2, ");
     else if(i>str && j>stc)
      System.out.print("7, ");
     else if(i>str && j<stc)
      System.out.print("5, ");
     else if(j>stc && i<str)
      System.out.print("1, ");
     else if(j<stc && i<str)
      System.out.print("3, ");
     stc=j;
    }
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not the same thing as Java.

Comment: @Travis Your original title was correct.